# Openwrt and sipproxy why I am unable to perform a call via a softphone?

Tags: networking, openwrt, voip, sip

I have setup in my router openwrt and I try to perform a call using my provider's VOIP settings that I retrieved for its router that provided. My network settings are the following:

```
config interface 'loopback'
    option device 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
    option ula_prefix 'fdd2:a40d:d919::/48'


config device 'wan_dsl0_dev'
    option name 'dsl0'
    option macaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

config atm-bridge 'atm'
    option vpi '1'
    option vci '32'
    option encaps 'llc'
    option payload 'bridged'
    option nameprefix 'dsl'

config dsl 'dsl'
        option annex 'b'
    option ds_snr_offset '0'
        option line_mode 'vdsl'
        option tone 'auto'        
        option firmware '/lib/firmware/vr9-B-dsl.bin' 

config device
    option name 'br-lan'
    option type 'bridge'
    list ports 'lan1'
    list ports 'lan2'
    list ports 'lan3'
    list ports 'lan4'

config interface 'lan'
    option device 'br-lan'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '60'

config interface 'wan'
    option device 'dsl0.835'
    option proto 'pppoe'
    option username 'username'
    option password 'password'
    option ipv6 'none'
    option keepalive '10'
    option mtu '1492'
    list dns '1.1.1.1'
    option peerdns '0'

config interface voip
    option device 'dsl0.837'
    option proto 'dhcp'

config interface 'wan6'
    option device '@wan'
    option proto 'dhcpv6'
```

As you can see, voip uses the vlan `dsl0.837`. Also, I have configured the siproxy like that as well:

```
config siproxd general
    # Custom options allow using OpenWRT network names, and defaults should
    # work out-of-the-box. If your SIP devices do not REGISTER externally,
    # you may also need to open firewall ports: tcp/udp 5060, udp 7070-7089.

    option interface_inbound lan
#   option interface_outbound dsl0.837

# All other documented siproxd configuration directives are supported. Use
# a UCI 'option' for single-instance directives, and UCI 'list' entries for
# directives that allow multiple instances, per the examples below.

    # Define low-level network devices, overriding interface_in/outbound:
#   option if_inbound eth0
    option if_outbound dsl0.837


    # Enable DEBUG logging for configuration messages:
#   option debug_level 0x00000100
#   option silence_log 0

    # Load two plugins: one that logs SIP call details to syslog, and one
    # that strips out G.729, GSM codecs:
#   list load_plugin 'plugin_logcall.so'
#   list load_plugin 'plugin_codecfilter.so'
#   list plugin_codecfilter_blacklist G729
#   list plugin_codecfilter_blacklist GSM

daemonize 1
masked_host=ngn.hol.net
outbound_proxy_host = ngn.hol.net
outbound_proxy_port = 5060
```

Then In my computer connected via ethernet to the LAN has ekiga configured like that:

[image: Ekiga settings]

But despite successfully connecting to voip, I am unable to perform a call to my cellphone (my provider offers landline call via SIP/VOIP). My provider is Vodafone in Greece.

I attempted ta call `sip:^my_cellphone_number^@192.168.1.1` (router's ip) but I am unable to do so. So do you know why?

My firewall settings are the following as well:

```
config defaults
    option syn_flood    1
    option input        ACCEPT
    option output       ACCEPT
    option forward      REJECT
# Uncomment this line to disable ipv6 rules
#   option disable_ipv6 1

config zone
    option name     lan
    list   network      'lan'
    option input        ACCEPT
    option output       ACCEPT
    option forward      ACCEPT

config zone
    option name     wan
    list   network      'wan'
    list   network      'wan6'
    option input        REJECT
    option output       ACCEPT
    option forward      REJECT
    option masq     1
    option mtu_fix      1

config forwarding
    option src      lan
    option dest     wan

# We need to accept udp packets on port 68,
# see https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/4108
config rule
    option name     Allow-DHCP-Renew
    option src      wan
    option proto        udp
    option dest_port    68
    option target       ACCEPT
    option family       ipv4

# Allow IPv4 ping
config rule
    option name     Allow-Ping
    option src      wan
    option proto        icmp
    option icmp_type    echo-request
    option family       ipv4
    option target       ACCEPT

config rule
    option name     Allow-IGMP
    option src      wan
    option proto        igmp
    option family       ipv4
    option target       ACCEPT

config rule
    option name     Allow-VOIP
    option src      lan
    option proto        udp 
    option src_port     5060
    option family           ipv4            
        option target           ACCEPT

config rule                            
        option name             Allow-VOIP  
        option src              lan       
        option proto            udp               
        option src_port         7070-7080            
        option family           ipv4      
        option target           ACCEPT     

# Allow DHCPv6 replies
# see https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/10381
config rule
    option name     Allow-DHCPv6
    option src      wan
    option proto        udp
    option src_ip       fc00::/6
    option dest_ip      fc00::/6
    option dest_port    546
    option family       ipv6
    option target       ACCEPT

config rule
    option name     Allow-MLD
    option src      wan
    option proto        icmp
    option src_ip       fe80::/10
    list icmp_type      '130/0'
    list icmp_type      '131/0'
    list icmp_type      '132/0'
    list icmp_type      '143/0'
    option family       ipv6
    option target       ACCEPT

# Allow essential incoming IPv6 ICMP traffic
config rule
    option name     Allow-ICMPv6-Input
    option src      wan
    option proto    icmp
    list icmp_type      echo-request
    list icmp_type      echo-reply
    list icmp_type      destination-unreachable
    list icmp_type      packet-too-big
    list icmp_type      time-exceeded
    list icmp_type      bad-header
    list icmp_type      unknown-header-type
    list icmp_type      router-solicitation
    list icmp_type      neighbour-solicitation
    list icmp_type      router-advertisement
    list icmp_type      neighbour-advertisement
    option limit        1000/sec
    option family       ipv6
    option target       ACCEPT

# Allow essential forwarded IPv6 ICMP traffic
config rule
    option name     Allow-ICMPv6-Forward
    option src      wan
    option dest     *
    option proto        icmp
    list icmp_type      echo-request
    list icmp_type      echo-reply
    list icmp_type      destination-unreachable
    list icmp_type      packet-too-big
    list icmp_type      time-exceeded
    list icmp_type      bad-header
    list icmp_type      unknown-header-type
    option limit        1000/sec
    option family       ipv6
    option target       ACCEPT

config rule
    option name     Allow-IPSec-ESP
    option src      wan
    option dest     lan
    option proto        esp
    option target       ACCEPT

config rule
    option name     Allow-ISAKMP
    option src      wan
    option dest     lan
    option dest_port    500
    option proto        udp
    option target       ACCEPT

# allow interoperability with traceroute classic
# note that traceroute uses a fixed port range, and depends on getting
# back ICMP Unreachables.  if we're operating in DROP mode, it won't
# work so we explicitly REJECT packets on these ports.
config rule
    option name     Support-UDP-Traceroute
    option src      wan
    option dest_port    33434:33689
    option proto        udp
    option family       ipv4
    option target       REJECT
    option enabled      false
```

Do I also need to open extra ports as well?

Comment: In my environment I have the VoIP devices registering directly with the SIP Registrar endpoint, and the router neither knows nor cares about SIP traffic. I couldn't work out why you're trying to Register with your router though

Comment: I try to register via router cause ant SIP registrations happen via a specific VLAN (`dsl0.837`) if the traffic towards to `ngn.hol.gr` does not pass through 837 vlan fails to perfoms any SIP/VOIP phone call. (Thats by ISP settings not mine)